# Display OpenCV+Gstreamer video. How to manage the window and GUI elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, gtk, gstreamer

I use Gstreamer pipeline to display video from OpenCV. Development environment - Python 3, Raspbian.

Part of the code:

```
...

pipeline_s = "appsrc ! queue ! v4l2convert ! autovideosink sync=false"
out = cv2.VideoWriter(pipeline_s, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, 0, 20.0, (1280,720))


while True:
    ret, frame = vs.read()
    if ret:
      out.write(frame)
      cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I don't use the **imshow** method for display because Gstreamer has a much better optimization for OpenGL on Raspberry Pi 4.

When launched, the video opens in a standard Qt or GTK window (depending on which GUI OpenCV was compiled with).

**How can I manage this window (full screen, minimize, close) and add my own controls (buttons, menus) in Python 3?**

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: You don't need GStreamer for what you're doing. You display video with `cv2.imshow` and add buttons as you like.

Comment: eyllanesc,

Unfortunately, displaying video on Raspberry 4 with Gstreamer pipline is more efficient than with imshow (24-28% of CPU load versus 35-50% respectively). This is due to the problem of GPU drivers for Raspberry 4. On Raspberry 3 the situation is reversed.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?? I have a similar issue